# ¿Por qué en un JMenuBar los items funcionan al segundo click y no al primero?

Tags: java, menú, click, jmenubar

Dispongo de un `JMenuBar` donde en él tengo varios `items`, al hacer click debería abrirme el contenido, sólo me lo abre si clickeo dos veces sobre el item (no doble click sino primero `clickeo`, salgo de las dimensiones del item, y vuelvo a pulsar - aquí si funciona-)

Código:

```
public class Index extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public Index() {
        initComponents();
        //Lanzar animación (hilos).
        Animacion a = new Animacion(this);
        a.start();
        System.out.println("¡Bienvenido a osmarentcars, administrador!");
        //Fondo del JFrame en color gris.
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.gray);
        //Código para confirmar el cierre de la ventana principal.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "¿Desea salir de la aplicación?", 
                        "Salir de la aplicación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE){
                    System.out.println("Saliendo de la aplicación... ¡Hasta luego!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });

        //Situamos el JDialog en el centro de la pantalla.
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //No redimensionable.
        setResizable(false);
    }

    private void lanzarAyuda(){
        try{
            //Carga el fichero de ayuda.
            File fichero = new File("sistema_ayuda" + File.separator + "helpset.hs");
            URL hsURL = fichero.toURI().toURL();

            //Crea el HelpSet.
            HelpSet helpset = new HelpSet(getClass().getClassLoader(), hsURL);
            HelpBroker hb = helpset.createHelpBroker();
            //Mostrar el sistema de ayuda al pulsar F1.
            hb.enableHelpOnButton(button_ayuda, "principal", helpset);
            hb.enableHelpKey(getRootPane(), "principal", helpset);

            //Colocamos la posicion de la ventana (Posicion p).
            hb.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
            //Colocamos el tamaño de la ventana (Dimension d).
            hb.setLocation(new Point(250,90));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void button_ayudaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_button_ayudaActionPerformed
        lanzarAyuda();
    }//GEN-LAST:event_button_ayudaActionPerformed

    private void button_webActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_button_webActionPerformed
        SubirHTMLaWeb s = new SubirHTMLaWeb();
        s.run();
    }//GEN-LAST:event_button_webActionPerformed

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Index.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Index.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Index.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Index.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Index().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Código del JMenuBar:

```
menu_menu.setText("Acerca de ...");

        button_ayuda.setText("Ayuda");
        button_ayuda.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                button_ayudaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        menu_menu.add(button_ayuda);

        button_web.setText("Subir página web");
        button_web.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                button_webActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        menu_menu.add(button_web);

        menubar.add(menu_menu);

        setJMenuBar(menubar);
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código que estas usando?

Comment: Editada ahora mismo.

Comment: No veo el `JMenuBar` por ningún sitio en el código que has puesto.

Comment: El menú JMenuBar no debe aparece en mi código, debe aparecer en el código creado al generar/arrastrar los componetes de la paleta de Java Swing al JFrame. Se inserta en "private void initComponents() {" automáticamente. Lo que yo sí programa es el evento al hacer click en el botón de un item de ese "JMenuBar".

Comment: Aún así, te dejo mi código generado del "JMenuBar".

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te está pasando es que la declaración de las clases de ayuda la estas haciendo en el momento de pinchar en el menú (el primer click), pero debería estar hecho antes.

Luego, en tu segundo click vuelves a definir tu ayuda, pero como está declarada de antes ya sí que te funciona.

Eso explicaría el comportamiento que te he entendido.

Para arreglarlo, declara los elementos de ayuda que tienes fuera del evento de click. Hazlo igual que declaras el resto de elementos de la ventana junto con los botones, el menú, etc... **después de haber instanciado los elementos a los que haces referencia en la ayuda (`button_ayuda`)**.

Con eso debería funcionar.

Comment: Tengo los elementos en una función lanzarAyuda() y esa función es llamada al hacer "click" en el botón "button_ayuda". Aún no entiendo el motivo de que ocurra al segundo click y no al primero. Perdona..., antes de probarlo prefiero entenderlo.

Comment: @omaza1990 es por lo que te explico en mi respuesta. Tienes que declarar la ayuda antes de usarla. Cuando le das "click" es para usarla, ya debe estar preparada. Tampoco se tarda tanto en probarlo, con que llames a tu método `lanzarAyuda()` también donde declaras el resto de elementos verás que te funciona después al primer click. Luego, para no duplicar deberías de separar declaración de uso para no repetirlo en cada click.